# Making empty textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

When I want to clear the following array:

```
userInfo[0] = txtPassword.Text;
userInfo[1] = txtVoornaam.Text;
userInfo[2] = txtAchternaam.Text;
userInfo[3] = txtWoonplaats.Text;
userInfo[4] = txtPostcode.Text;
userInfo[5] = txtTelnr.Text;
```

I'm doing the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
  userInfo[i] = "";
}
```

That obviously doesn't work and when I try this:

```
foreach (string item in userInfo)
{
  item = "";
}
```

Also does not work. How can I do this without saying:

```
userinfo[0] = txtPassword;
```

Comment: Well `userinfo[0] = txtPassword` won't compile.  Also `userInfo[0] = txtPassword.Text` may not have the same effect as `userInfo[0] = ""` if the contents of the control isn't _empty_

Comment: What is `userInfo` ? a `string[]` ? Why does `userInfo[i] = ""` 'not work'?

Comment: Maybe you should tell us what `userInfo[]` is _defined as_

Comment: Yes userInfo is a string[].

Comment: But when I say userInfo[i] = "" nothing happens.

Comment: If you want to empty those textboxes either write them out or stuff them into a  List<TextBox> ! You did ask about emptying the array though!!

Comment: What is `txtPassword` defined as?  As I said, that last line won't compile if `txtPassword` is a `TextBox`

Comment: txtPassword is a textbox. But if I have to put everything in an array as a textbox I'm doing things twice.

Comment: By default there's no link between your array and the textboxes. So, if you want to clear the array and the textboxes, you'll have to clear them separately.

Comment: If you want to treat them array-like, you need to add them to an array, or rather and MUCH better a List<TextBox>. Do it once and you can loop over it for any or your needs..

Comment: @StephenKennedy that was metrogrid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to treat them array-like, you need to add them to an array, or rather and **much** better a `List<TextBox>`. Do it **once** and you can loop over it for **any** or your needs..

Do it once..:

```
List<TextBox> boxes = new List<TextBox>()
           { txtPassword, txtVoornaam, txtAchternaam, txtWoonplaats, txtPostcode, txtTelnr};
```

Now you can pull out the values into a string array

```
string[] myTexts = boxes.Select(x => x.Text).ToArray();
```

..or a List :

```
List<string> myTexts = boxes.Select(x => x.Text).ToList();
```

or you can clear them all:

```
foreach (TextBox tb in boxes) tb.Text = "";
```

If you need to you can access the `List` elements by variable:

```
boxes.Find(x => x == textBox2).Text = "12345";
```

..or by `Name`:

```
boxes.Find(x => x.Name == "txtVoornaam").Text = "Jens";
```

(All checks omitted..)